# Problems with changing mac-address of Raspberry Pi

Tags: networking, archlinux, ethernet

I want to change the mac address of `eth0` of my Raspberry Pi.
I haven't any problems with the `wlan0` (`macchanger -A wlan0` works)

General information: I have

- a Raspberry Pi Model B
- with Arch Linux ARM (archlinux-hf-2013-06-06)

I used

```
# macchanger -A eth0
```

and get this result

```
Current MAC:   b8:27:eb:bc:d5:fd (Raspberry Pi Foundation)
Permanent MAC: 00:00:00:00:00:00 (Xerox Corporation)
[ERROR] Could not change MAC: interface up or insufficient permissions: Device or resource busy
```

and

```
# ifconfig eth0 down hw ether 01:02:03:04:05:06
```

with this error

```
SIOCSIFHWADDR: Cannot assign requested address
```

I googled a bit and found [this](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?p=90975). I think there is someone with the same problem but I can't find a solution.

The question is now: Why i get these error messages (when do macchanger / ifconfig makes such an output?) and maybe what can I do to remove them and finally change the mac address?

Comment: would you prefer a C code to do the MAC setting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Write a script

   ```
   #!/bin/sh

   ifconfig eth0 down hw ether 00:00:00:00:00:00
   ifconfig eth0 up
   ```

where "00:00:00:00:00:00" - your mac address
Let's say you called it mac.sh.

2. Put it in the /etc/init.d/ directory. And make this file executable using
   `# chmod +x mac.sh`
3. Then run:
   `# update-rc.d mac.sh defaults`

That's make your script bootable.

4. After rebooting mac will be changed

I got this from internet.

Answer (score 3):

Did you forgot `sudo`? So try `sudo macchanger -A eth0`
And why you want to change the mac address?

Comment: no i was logged in as root (look at the '#', if you are a normal user you will get a '$')

Comment: Ow sorry! I probably looked over it!

Answer (score 1):

Just add `smsc95xx.macaddr=00:00:00:00:00:00` to `/boot/cmdline.txt`.